# finding the big oh estimate of the a simple print function

Tags: c++, big-o, cout

```
while (num > 1)
{
    cout << "num is now " << num << endl;
    cout << "hello // \n";
    num /= 2;
}
```

I am trying to give the big O estimate for the print statements.

The user gets to input `num`. I tried a few inputs and am starting to see a pattern.

- 1 gives 0 print.
- 2-3 gives 1 print.
- 4-7 gives 2 prints.
- 8-15 gives 3 prints.
- 16-31 gives 4 prints.

let `p = the number of prints`. I see that the range of numbers giving you a certain amount of prints is `2^p`.
So is the big O estimate `2^p` ?

Comment: floor(log2 (p)) actually. You got it the wrong way around: you want to know, how many times you print based on input, not how many you need to input for a print.

Comment: `p` is the output (what you want to calculate), not the input. The answer should be in the form: `p = someFunctionOf(num)`.

Comment: In this case the big O is a function describing the number of loops for some `num`.

Comment: Look at the last slide of this document -> [link](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt).

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely thinking in the right direction and what is more important - you are approaching the problem in the correct manner. Still your final conclusion is a bit off the target. Try to use 2<sup>p</sup> for the values you've computed and you will see that the number of prints is not 2<sup>p</sup>, but rather the inverse of this function.

Answer (score 1):

It's `O(log N)`. The reason is that your halving the range with each iteration. If you're familar with binary search then your loop if doing something similar.

You've correctly observed the  `2^p` pattern. The inverse of this is log base-2 (rather than log base-10). When people mention `log` in big-O notation they typically mean the base-2 version.

Comment: Actually, the base doesn't matter. O(log N) could be in any base because the only difference is a constant factor, which is disregarded in big-O notation.

Answer (score 0):

just use the master theorem.

[Link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

b = 2 f(n) = 1 a = 1.